# Winapi CreateProcess File Permissions

Tags: c, winapi

I'm currently writing some software that has two different programs using the winapi (a parser and an interpreter). I would like to call the parser from the interpreter, so I am using the `CreateProcessA` function. However, when the parser tries to open a file, it throws a Permission Denied error, and I'm not too sure why.

Calling the parser on its own, and not from the interpreter, works perfectly fine.

According to [CreateProcessA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN), "The new process runs in the security context of the calling process," so it seems like this other program shouldn't have any issues with permissions since I can open files from the interpreter.

Is there something that I'm missing with `CreateProcessA` that would make it change file permissions for the child process?

Here is a snippet of code for the interpreter (note that I've left out error checking to make the code simpler to show here):

```
// These are just used to open pipes so I can extract stdout
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sec = {0};
sec.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sec.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
sec.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

HANDLE stdout_rd, stdout_wr;

CreatePipe(&stdout_rd, &stdout_wr, &sec, 0);
SetHandleInformation(stdout_rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

STARTUPINFO startInfo = {0};
startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
startInfo.hStdError = stdout_wr;
startInfo.hStdOutput = stdout_wr;
startInfo.hStdInput = NULL;
startInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = {0};

char *command = "parser /path/to/file.txt";
CreateProcessA(NULL, command, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &startInfo, &processInfo);

// Do more stuff to print out stdout from child process
```

Here is a snippet of code from the parser:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // This call throws the error:
    // Error: Permission denied

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    // Parse File
}
```

Here is a snippet of code from the interpreter that opens and closes the file.

```
HANDLE file = CreateFileA("/path/to/file.txt", GENERIC_READ,
    0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

FILETIME writeTime = {0};
GetFileTime(file, NULL, NULL, &writeTime);

CloseHandle(file);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need 2 separate processes, instead of just 2 threads in a single process?

Comment: I actually didn't think about that. Can you run a separate executable from a thread without a different process?

Comment: my point is, do you really need 2 executables? Why not 1 executable that runs the interpreter and parser logic in separate threads? In any case, does your interpreter ever open the file that the parser is trying to access? If so, does it close the file before starting the parser? Have you tried using `CreateFile()` instead of `fopen()` to get more granular error reporting? "Permissi8n denied" is pretty broad, could be caused by a number of reasons.

Comment: Mainly because the files that get parsed are different from the ones that get interpreted. It's common to parse 20 or more files, then interpret only one of them. This is for VHDL if you're curious. It's also useful to figure out all the parse errors before you have to interpret the whole system. Yes, I do open the file to check the last modified time stamp, but I close the file immediately after. I'll add a code stub for that to the question.

Comment: I'll try using CreateFile instead of fopen

Comment: what you describe doesn't require multiple **processes** when multiple **threads** would suffice.

Comment: Well the other aspect is that the parsing and interpreting happens at different times. When you're writing the vhdl code, you'll make some files, parse them, make some more files and parse them, and then when you're done with the whole system, you'll interpret them. This type of workflow lends itself to having multiple tools that are separate from each other. I know that I could just use threads, and in fact it may just be easier to compile the parsing code into the interpreter as well, so I can just call it, but that would be an invasive change (This is a pretty big system)

Comment: *"`char *command = "parser /path/to/file.txt";`"* - Have you verified that `/path/to/file.txt` is indeed interpreted as a single command line argument? What are the values you get from `argc` and `argv` arguments?

Comment: open file with read only access ( `GENERIC_READ` ) but with no share access - wrong. you need set `FILE_SHARE_READ` how minimum. also think you got not access denied but share violation error

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I verified that it is a single command line argument. The path that I'm currently using didn't have any spaces, and in any case, `argc` is 2, and I printed `argv[1]` to verify that it was the correct path. Since it's possible for a path to have spaces in it, would it be better to wrap the file path in quotes?

Comment: @RbMm thanks, I didn't know about `FILE_SHARE_READ`, so I'll try using that. I already switched to memory mapped files, as I said in the comment on the answer, but when I get a little more time tonight or tomorrow I'll try switching back and using `FILE_SHARE_READ` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that problem is in the file permissions. If you could write file somewhere, you clearly should be able to read it with the same access token. You could get `Access Denied` error because file is still open by the interpreter process in the exclusive mode. You could either check that file is closed before calling `CreateProcess`, or use `CreateFile` to read and write with `FILE_SHARE_*` flags. However it could lead to other errors, if interpreter does not complete all file write operations before parser tries to use it.

As an alternative to files in this scenario you could use memory mapped files (`CreateFileMapping`, `MapViewOfFile`), to share data buffers between different processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I made sure that I closed the file after using it. I switched it over to a file mapping like you suggested, and that worked out. I might run into an issue trying to write out more data to the file than is allocated in the mapping, but I haven't had that problem yet. I'll probably look more into the Access Denied problem later since that's probably a better solution overall, but for now the file mapping got it done!

Comment: *You could get Access Denied error because file is still open by the interpreter process in the exclusive mode.* - no. in this case error will be `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`